# How to restrict TextView size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-xml

I'd like to have a box which contains two textviews, a title, and a text, which length can be long or not.
Like this:

[image: enter link description here]

Currently, what I have is: if the text is too big, it goes over the title.
The box can be with whatever layout you want (relative, constraint…)...

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: u can solve this issue by using constraint layout https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html

Comment: A ConstraintLayout is also a reasonable way to go here (constrain the title to the top+left and the other text to the top+right of the parent, and the second text to the right of the title with a bias of 1), but there's no reason to use a Barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the title won't ever be "too long", the easiest solution would be to use a `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` and `gravity` on the second `TextView`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="title"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        tools:text="some very very very very very very very very long text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```